# C# Nested Tasks -> Get time when tasks are over

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

i want to show the time my background tasks need for doing some work.

I have:

```
   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            sw.Start();
            function();
            sw.Stop();
        }
        ).ContinueWith(t => StatusText =sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

and the function looks something like this:

```
    function()
{
Task.Run({...});
Task.Run({...});
}
```

Now my Stopwatch just shows me a millisecond value because of the nested tasks. how can i show the real time my task needs to complete all the work in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either `await` or `Task.WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)` in your `function()`

Your code could look like this:

```
function()
{
    Task.WaitAll(
        Task.Run({...}),
        Task.Run({...})
    );
}
```